# Elasticsearch PHP bulk index performance vs index

Tags: php, performance, elasticsearch, bulk

I run a benchmark on elasticsearch using elasticsearch-php.
I compare the time taken by 10 000 index one by one vs 10 000 with bulk of 1 000 documents.

On my vpn server 3 cores 2 Gb mem the performance is quite the same with or without bulk index.

My php code (inspired by à post):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);  //  no timeout
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$es = new Elasticsearch\Client([
    'hosts'=>['127.0.0.1:9200']
]);
$max = 10000;

// ELASTICSEARCH BULK INDEX
$temps_debut = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i <=  $max; $i++) {
    $params['body'][] = array(
        'index' => array(
            '_index' => 'articles',
            '_type' => 'article',
            '_id' => 'cle' . $i
        )
    );
    $params['body'][] = array(
        'my_field' => 'my_value' . $i
    );
    if ($i % 1000) {   // Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request
        $responses = $es->bulk($params);
        $params = array();  // erase the old bulk request    
        unset($responses); // unset  to save memory
    }
}
$temps_fin = microtime(true);
echo 'Elasticsearch bulk: ' . round($i / round($temps_fin - $temps_debut, 4)) . ' per sec <br>';

// ELASTICSEARCH WITHOUT BULK INDEX
$temps_debut = microtime(true);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {    
            $params = array();
            $params['index'] = 'my_index';
            $params['type']  = 'my_type';
            $params['id']    = "key".$i;
            $params['body']  = array('testField' => 'valeur'.$i);
            $ret = $es->index($params);
        }
$temps_fin = microtime(true);
echo 'Elasticsearch One by one : ' . round($i / round($temps_fin - $temps_debut, 4)) . 'per sec <br>';
?>
```

Elasticsearch bulk: 1209 per sec
Elasticsearch One by one : 1197per sec

Is there something wrong on my bulk index to obtain better performance ?

Thank's

Comment: I think the problem because you put $es->bulk($params) inside loop, let's try put them outside loop.

Comment: The speed difference is really noticeable if you're having to send the data over a network. You're not going to manage anything like 1000 per second if you're using cURL to send them one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
if ($i % 1000) {   // Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request
```

with:

```
if (($i + 1) % 1000 === 0) {   // Every 1000 documents stop and send the bulk request
```

or you will query for each non-0 value (that is 999 of 1000)...
Obviously, this only works if `$max` is a multiple of 1000.

Also, correct this bug:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <=  $max; $i++) {
```

will iterate over `$max + 1` items. replace it with:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
```

There might also be a problem with how you initialize `$params`. Shouldn't you set it up outside of the loop and only clean-up the `$params['body']` after each `->bulk()`? When you reset with `$params = array();` you loose all of it.

Also, remember that ES may be distributed over a cluster. Bulk operations can then be distributed to even the workload. So some performance scaling is not visible on a single physical node.